# Angular ui-router $stateProvider.state's url attribute

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was testing ui-router for my application and wanted to have a default state for my route.

For example, when I go to localhost:3000/r, I can load either /a or /b in the page given as,

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider.state('a', {
           templateUrl : '/a',
           url : '',
           controller  : 'mainController'
       })
       .state('b', {
           templateUrl : '/b',
           url : '',
           controller  : 'mainController'
       });
});
```

**What exactly is the significance or the url attribute**? If i leave it blank it acts as a default state for my route localhost:3000/r and loads /a into the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject another provider to your config function, that will be used to set the default route
And you need to set urls for your current states (a,b)

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/a");
   $stateProvider.state('a', {
        templateUrl : '/a',
        url : '/a',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
    .state('b', {
        templateUrl : '/b',
        url : '/b',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    });
});
```

By doing this, your default route will be "/a"